# Terminator windows group but won't ungroup

Tags: linux, vim, terminator

When working in Terminator, my terminals will group if I press Alt-a, but I can't find any way to make them ungroup. I did this accidentally; Super+g is supposed to group terminals (and it does), and Super+Shift+g is supposed to ungroup terminals.

Super+Shift+g works for ungrouping terminals if they are grouped with Super+g but doesn't work if they are grouped with Alt-a.

I did this by mistake when working in Vim - while in insert mode I use Alt-b to go the previous word and then to go to the end of line and get back into insert mode by pressing Shift-A (except I hit Alt instead of Shift).

Comment: Just took a look in the terminator prefs, and i can't even see any keybiding of Alt + a at all. Shift (+Super) + G/T are the only valid grouping/ungrouping keybindings

Comment: @GregKasapidis Yes. That's the same thing that I see. I have no idea why it's doing this. Did you try Alt + a with multiple terminals open to see if this happens on your end?

Comment: Yes, nothing happens at all when using Alt + A.

Comment: @GregKasapidis Strange. It doesn't happen on my other machines either. Thanks for trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

Hey so I was able to recreate this.

Alt+a will link all panes/windows I have for terminal when I type input.

I cannot identify a way to stop this without closing all terminals, which ironically is very easy when you can enter commands into them all at once.